# Problema con función char* (C++)

Tags: c++, c, function, sprintf

tengo el siguiente encabezado:

`char* date(int d, int m, int y);`

En el que se ingresan 3 valores que corresponden al día, mes y año respectivamente. Esta función debe retornar "d/m/y", y sé que debo utilizar sprintf, pero aún así no estaría entiendo cómo hacerlo.

Se me ocurrió hacer lo siguiente:

```
char output[100];
sprintf(output,"%d/%d/%d", d, m, y);
printf("%s",output);
return output;
```

Pero a la hora de compilar me salta el aviso:
`address of local variable 'output' returned`
Y señala la línea de código `char output[100];`

No logro ver cómo solucionarlo, si me pueden ayudar se agradecería. Gracias.

Comment: que librería estas usando?

Comment: estoy usando stdio.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si la traduces, la advertencia significa:

> La dirección de la variable local "output" es devuelta.

Las variables y los parámetros  viven en un determinado ámbito. `output` vive en la función `date`.

Al finalizar la ejecución de la función, todas sus variables dejan de existir. Por lo que estás devolviendo una dirección de memoria que ya no contiene la información que esperas. [Más información](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/lifetime).

---

Cuando quieres que cierta información permanezca en memoria, usas el **heap**.

Si estás en C tendrás que usar [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) y [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) para reservar y liberar memoria respectivamente.

El código se vería así:

```
// Reservas memoria en bytes.
// sizeof devuelve los bytes que ocupa una variable de tipo char.
// Se multiplica ese valor por 100 que son la cantidad de elementos.
char* output = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));

// Haces lo que tengas que hacer con la memoria
...

// Al terminar de usarla la liberas para que vuelva
// a estar disponible para su uso.
free(output);
```

En C++ es más simple:

```
// Reservas memoria pasando el número de elementos
// que quieres entre corchetes.
char* output = new char[100];

...

// Liberas la memoria.
delete[] output;
```

Aunque estando en C++ sugiero que uses las estructuras que te brinda, por ejemplo [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) y no tendrás que preocuparte tan seguido por este tipo de cosas. Tu código se vería así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string date(int d, int m, int y){
    std::string output;
    output += d;
    output += '/';
    output += m;
    output += '/';
    output += y;
    std::cout << output;
    return output;
}
```

---

Alternativamente puedes hacer que quien llame la función tenga que pasar la dirección de memoria con la que trabajar.

Por ejemplo:

```
void date(char* output, int d, int m, int y){
    sprintf(output, "%d/%d/%d", d, m, y);
    printf("%s",output);
}

int main(){
    char buffer[100];
    date(buffer, 1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```